# iFilter msg content not retrieved

Tags: email, msg, ifilter

I'm using Windows Server 2012 (64bit) and am investigating using iFilters as a means of extracting and indexing data from various file types.

One of the file types is .msg (MS email).  The iFilter is mostly doing its job and retrieving the text as requested but it fails to retrieve the email content.  I can't find anyone complaining of the same problem so suspect I am doing something wrong but cannot work out what it is; especially when all the other filetypes work correctly.

I've tried adding the Windows Search feature and reviewed the Indexing Options to ensure .msg iFilters are set to retrieve properties and content.  All fine there and I doubt that would cause it anyway as I'm not using the Windows Search feature.

I've used the iFilters that come as default in with an Office 2013 installation and have also tried the iFilters that come with the Microsoft Office 2010 Filter Pack (up to service pack 2).  All without any difference in my findings.

I'm out of ideas now so thought I'd pose the problem here.  Anyone got any thoughts...?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a software development problem.

Comment: What do you think it sounds like?  Should I be raising this question on another stack exchange community?

Comment: Well, a software development problem could be like "I wrote this code and it does some unexpected crap" or "I've developed my own IFilter and can't figure out how to register it" or "I'm trying to tune this software development tool and have no luck". The problem you're having is about setting up an existing IFilter crafted by someone else. It's unlikely a good fit here - perhaps somewhere like SuperUser it'll fit better.

Comment: Thanks, will try there.  I am wrapping this into some software I'm developing hence my posting here.  But I get your point.

Comment: We've developed a custom iFilter and have problems registering it, so I'd be interested in your other posts, can you put links to them in this question?